# why openprocess function return different handle each time?

Tags: c++, c, windows, handle

I want to get the process and thread handles about some games to inject dll, and I used `OpenProcess()` and `OpenThread()` to obtain these handles. But I found that I just get different handles each time I use these functions. And they are useless for me because they arent the true handles. Please tell me how I can get the true handles?

Thanks for your answers and comments! And I found that I did not describe my problem very well. Sorry.

Actually, if i used `CreateProcess()` funtion to launch a process and get handles from parameter `lpProcessInformation pi`. I could inject my dll into game through these handles named `pi.hProcess` and `pi.hThread`. And these handles seem like would not change during the program's runtime.

But if I got handles from `OpenProcess()` and `OpenThread()`, the process handle and thread handle were not same as the handle from `CreateProcess()` even though I got them in same run from a process.

So I thought that the handle from `pi` is the true handle, and the handle from `OpenProcess()` are fake. I dont know why they are different and why only handles from `pi` can work well.

Please tell me the difference about handles from `OpenProcess()` and
`CreateProcess()`. Or how I can get the handles same as `CreateProcess()` through PID.

This is the code how inject dll. And ony handles from **pi.hProcess** and **pi.hThread** can work.

```
void KInject::InjectDll(HANDLE hProcess, HANDLE hThread, ULONG_PTR param){  
    QueueUserAPC(
        (PAPCFUNC)GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandleA("kernel32.dll"), "LoadLibraryA"),
        hThread, 
        (ULONG_PTR)param
        );  
}

void KInject::Inject2(HANDLE hProcess, HANDLE hThread, const char* szDLL ){
    SIZE_T len = strlen(szDLL) + 1;
    PVOID param = VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, NULL, len, MEM_COMMIT | MEM_TOP_DOWN /*MEM_RESERVE*/, PAGE_READWRITE);  
    if (param != NULL)  
    {  
        SIZE_T ret;
        if (WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, param, szDLL, len, &ret)) {  
            InjectDll(hProcess, hThread, (ULONG_PTR)param );   
        }  
    }
}
```

This is the code how i get handles.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include "tlhelp32.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    HWND hq = FindWindow(NULL, "Temp");
    RECT rect;
    DWORD dwThreadID;
    DWORD dwProcessId;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(hq, &dwProcessId);
    GetWindowRect(hq, &rect);
    DWORD a = GetWindowThreadProcessId(hq, &dwProcessId);

    THREADENTRY32 te32 = { sizeof(te32) };
    HANDLE hThreadSnap = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPTHREAD, 0);
    if (Thread32First(hThreadSnap, &te32))
    {
        do {
            if (dwProcessId == te32.th32OwnerProcessID)
            {
                dwThreadID = te32.th32ThreadID;
                break;
            }
        } while (Thread32Next(hThreadSnap, &te32));
    }
    CloseHandle(hThreadSnap);
    HANDLE  hProcess = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwProcessId);  
    HANDLE  hThread = OpenThread(THREAD_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, dwThreadID);
    CloseHandle(hThread);
    CloseHandle(hProcess);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *But I found that I just get different handles each time I use these functions* - and so what ? *And they are useless for me because they arent the true handles.* - why you decide this. `OpenProcess` and `OpenThread` if not fail, return "true" handles

Comment: The system is opening and closing processes and threads all the time. How would getting the same handle each time be useful to it, or essential for you? You simply use the handle it gives you. If you check in your coat to a cloakroom, you don't expect the same ticket number each time.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by a "true" handle? This question is extremely confusing. What's wrong with the handles you are getting exactly? If two calls gave the same handle, what would happen when one of the callers closed the handle?

Answer (score 4):

There is nothing wrong with the API in this regard. Their return values are just what they are supposed to be, i.e. "handles" to the actual processes and threads. Exactly the same way as when you open a file, you get a handle to it, and if you open the same file multiple times, you may get different handles.

Having said that, just in the same way that files do have a more permanent name—which is their *paths*—processes and threads also do have a more permanent name and its called their "ID".

You can use the Win32 functions `GetProcessId(HANDLE handle)` and `GetThreadId(HANDLE handle)` to get to these more permanent identifiers.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And im so sorry that i didnt describe my problem completely. Actually, if i used Createprocess() funtion to launch a process and get handles from pi. I could inject my dll into game through these handles. But if i get handles from Openprocess() and OpenThread(), it could not work well. So i thought that the handle from pi is the true handle, and the handles from OpenProcess() are fake. Please tell me the difference about handles from Openprocess and Createprocess. Or how i can get the handles same as Createprocess through PID. Many thanks!

Comment: What do you mean when you say "fails"? You have to get the error code (typically using `GetLastError()`) and research why that particular error happens. Also, remember that "ALL_ACCESS" privilege probably doesn't really mean "all access"! Windows security model is weird.

Comment: no,no. It didnt occur any error. It just be useless when i use handles from OpenProcess(). In my posted inject function InjectDll() above. It only success when i used handles from CreateProcess().

Comment: Sorry, im not quite familiar with handles. Please tell me does the handle created by CreatProcess() or OpenProcess() have the same privilege? Or the handle from CreateProcess() has higher rights?
It was so sad that only handle from CreateProcess() can be used to inject dll in my code and i only can get handles from OpenProcess().

Comment: When your DLL injection fails, it probably fails in some Win32 API. Investigate *that* error. It could be a privilege problem, or something else entirely.

Comment: I checked returned value from GetLastError() and it showed that inject function worked successfully, though i used handle from OpenProcess(). But it still useless in the game. So i thought there might be some difderence in privilege between handles from CreatProcess and OpenProcess.

Comment: Or the handle i got from OpenProcess() could not controll the game entirely as the handle from CreateProcess().

Comment: So my current problem is how to get the create–handle without using CreatProcess().